# android ObjectAnimator pivot points

Tags: android, imageview

Good day.

I would appreciate some help if possible, please.

The code below works PERFECTLY to move an imageView to x = 200 and y = 100. Following this move, the ImageView rotates through 360 degrees about the centre (0,0) position.

How can I set a pivotX and pivotY value AT X = 200 and Y = 100  pLEASE ?

Thanking you in advance.

Paul

```
public void onButtonClickRotate(View v) {

    ObjectAnimator animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationX",  200f);

    ObjectAnimator animatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationY",  100f)
                .setDuration(100);

    ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView,"rotation",  0f, 360f)
                .setDuration(1000);

    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();


    set.playSequentially(animatorX, animatorY,rotation);
        set.setDuration(2000);
        set.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To rotate on the pivot points use something like this:

```
val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
val pivotY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "pivotX", 30f)
val pivotX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "pivotY", 70F)
val animR = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotation", 0F, 360F)
AnimatorSet().apply {
    playTogether(animX, animY, animR)
    start()
}
```

Just set your desired pivot values. Make sure to check the guide on Property Animation here for more details and other (perhaps better) ways of doing this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation

Answer (score 1):

In my use case the following worked:

```kotlin
// set pivot point of the object
imageView.pivotX = pX
imageView.pivotY = pY

// start rotation animation. e.g. Y axes
oaY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            imageView,
            "rotationY",
            0f, 360f, 0f)
oaY.start()
```